# Can a NavigationLink perform an async function when navigating to another view?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

I'm trying to create a navigation link in SwiftUI that logs in a user and navigates to the next screen.

I've tried using .simultaneousGesture as shown below, based on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57666620/is-it-possible-for-a-navigationlink-to-perform-an-action-in-addition-to-navigati). When I have it perform a simple action (e.g. print("hello")), the code works fine and navigates to the next page, but when I have it perform my authState.signUp function (which is async), it calls the function but doesn't navigate to the next page.

Is there a different way I should be approaching this?

```
NavigationLink(destination: NextView()) {
    Text("Create account")
}
.simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded {
    authState.signUp(user: user)
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a selection arg of navigationLink

add this var

```
@State var trigger: Bool? = nil
```

and use

```
NavigationLink(destination: NextView(), tag: true,
                                   selection: $trigger ) {
}
```

when ever your other job (login) is done toggle() the trigger and navigationLink fires.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using a very similar strategy of setting a trigger state variable, but I used isActive instead of tag and selection within the NavigationLink.

Comment: great happy to help.

Comment: NavigationLink has been deprecated.  Is there a way of doing this with the new navigation stack API's?