# Why onTapGesture and NavigationLink doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mobile, swiftui

I was wondering why my NavigationLink doesn't work with onTapGesture modifier, onTapGesture work fine, but navigationlink doesn't.

Some sample of code:

```
NavigationView{
            VStack{
            NavigationLink{SongListView(audio: Sound.testData)
                    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                    .navigationBarTitle("")
                    .navigationBarHidden(true)
                
            } label:{
                BigCardView(title: "Anxiety relief", audioInfo: "7 audio files", image: "night", horizontalLines: 7, genre:self.genre.genreFilter)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        self.genre.genreFilter = "anxiety"
                    }
            }
    
            NavigationLink{SongListView(audio: Sound.testData)
                    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                    .navigationBarTitle("")
                    .navigationBarHidden(true)
                
            } label:{
                BigCardView(title: "Affirmations", audioInfo: "2 audio files", image: "affir", horizontalLines: 2, genre:self.genre.genreFilter)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        self.genre.genreFilter = "affirmations"
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: On tap gesture will intercept the gesture and will prevent it to be sent to the navigation link. Look at simultaneousGesture

Comment: How can I avoid that?

Comment: Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57666620/is-it-possible-for-a-navigationlink-to-perform-an-action-in-addition-to-navigati)

Comment: This is exactly what I searched for, thank you! simultaneousGesture did the thing I want. Thank you so much!