# SwiftUI code runs in the simulator but app does not appear in the simulator's home screen

Tags: swiftui, xcode15

The following simple SwiftUI code runs in the Xcode simulator. As soon as it appears, I hit Shift-Command-H to go to the Home screen. The app (which I have named TestApp) does not appear in the Home screen. There are no errors shown in the Xcode console at this point. Other apps which I have built during my SwiftUI learning process do not behave this way. What is a possible reason for this?

```
import SwiftUI

@Observable
class SecurityQuestions {
    var questions = ["", "", ""]
    var answers = ["", "", ""]
}

struct SecurityQuestionsView: View {
    @Bindable var securityQuestions: SecurityQuestions
    @Binding var path: NavigationPath
    var questionNum: Int
    
    @State private var question = ""
    @State private var answer = ""

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section {
                TextField("Question no. \(questionNum)", text: $securityQuestions.questions[questionNum - 1])
            }
            
            Section {
                TextField("Answer", text: $securityQuestions.answers[questionNum - 1])
            }
            
            Section {
                if questionNum < 3 {
                    NavigationLink("Go to question \(questionNum + 1)", value: questionNum)
                    
                } else {
                    NavigationLink(destination: EmptyView()) {
                        Text("Back to Question 1")
                    }
                    // NavigationLink (unlike Button) doesn't have an init
                    // that provides a closure to execute an action.
                    // Below is a hack to introduce a closure to execute
                    // an action,i.e., generic Swift Code that doesn't
                    // return a View.
                    /*
                     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57666620/is-it-possible-for-a-navigationlink-to-perform-an-action-in-addition-to-navigati
                    */
                    .gesture(TapGesture().onEnded {
                        path.removeLast(path.count)
                    })
                }
            }
            .font(.title)
        }
        .navigationTitle("Question \(questionNum)")
        .navigationDestination(for: Int.self) { qNum in
            SecurityQuestionsView(
                securityQuestions: securityQuestions,
                path: $path,
                questionNum: qNum + 1)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var path = NavigationPath()
    @State private var securityQuestions = SecurityQuestions()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            SecurityQuestionsView(
                securityQuestions: securityQuestions,
                path: $path,
                questionNum: 1)
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

Comment: Check whether the simulated home screen has multiple pages and your app is on another page. Also, look for your app in the simulated home screen's App Library (which is after the last page of app icons).

Answer (score 0):

Problem "solved" by copying and pasting all my code to a brand new Xcode project. The previous project still continues to have a missing app icon (the generic one) on the Simulator Home screen despite my restarting Xcode and doing a "Clean Build Folder..." I don't know why that is happening but at least now I have an app icon on the Home screen by creating a new project.

Comment: Another time, you could try performing a reset on the simulator (Device > Erase All Content And Settings...) and/or closing Xcode and deleting Project Build Data and Indexes from the storage settings (About This Mac > More Info... > Storage Settings... > Developer).

Comment: Yes, Device > Erase All Content And Settings allowed my missing TestApp to appear again on the Home Screen. Thanks!